# Nav bar spans width of initial screen but doesn't span upon scroll to match width of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have tried for the past 2 hours changing CSS up like `width:100%`, or `width:100vw`, but so far nothing is working.

At the moment, the nav bar does fit the entire width of the screen on desktop browsers so there is no initial problem there. However this page displays a dynamic table that grows in width when new columns are added.

Sadly, the nav bar will not span the full length of the width of the table. So upon scrolling across the page, the table does grow but the nav bar does not match the width of the table. So the width of the nav bar is much more narrow than the width of the table.

The class `table-container` is right now commented out but this doesn't work also when it's uncommented out.

Here is my current code. Please if you can help, I'd really appreciate it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flask Web Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      zoom: 175%;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      display: flex;
      width: 100vw;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #AAC939;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .form-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    label {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    /* .table-container {
          width: 100%;
        } */
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<!--                                              BODY                 -->

<body style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Section 1</a>
    <a class="active" href="{{ url_for('show_table') }}">Section 2</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('admin') }}">Section 3</a>
  </div>

  <header>
    <title>Form Data</title>
  </header>

  <div class="table-container">
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped" style="max-width:100%; white-space:nowrap">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {% for column_name in column_names %}
          <th>{{ column_name|replace('_', ' ') }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
          {% for item in row %}
          <td>{{ item|replace('_', ' ') }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You first need to correct the double `<body>` definition in your HTML code and move `<title>` into `<header>`.

Comment: I have fixed that now Rene, and edited the question with the changes. Thanks for the heads up. Have you any ideas about the nav bar issue?

Comment: You've made the `navbar` viewport width dependent, while you want it `table` width dependent. When the table overflows to the right because of extra cells, the navbar is still as wide as the vp, while the table grows wider than the vp. BTW, fix your snippet above too! Haven't checked for a solution, but maybe `body, .topnav { width: 100%  }` will suffice... I don't use BS, you will need help from others for that.

Comment: If you put your nav bar and the table into the _same_ container and made that container `inline-block`, then this _might_ have a chance of working - but with two elements that even don't have such a relation within a common parent, I don't see how you could achieve this without JavaScript. (But then a table that grows in width upon scrolling, is probably dependent on some JS you didn't show us in the first place, I suppose?)

Comment: Thank you for putting the problem so eloquently. I have tried setting width: 100% to both - sadly, it doesn't fix it @RenevanderLende

Comment: I think you better edit the snippet again and add actual generated table rows and cols for SO ppl to have some actual data to toy with. It doesn't look like a BS specific issue to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demo purposes, I gave `.table-container` a `min-width: 4000px` to resemble the table growing in width.

My initial thought is to set `.topnav` to `fixed` so it's always in the viewport when scrolling on the x-axis.

However, if your table has an unknown amount of sections. I would just add a bit of JS and use `getComputedStyle` to make `.topnav` the same width as `.table-container`.

```js
window.onload = function setWidth() {
  var tableWidth = document.getElementById("tableWidth");
  var navWidth = document.getElementById("navWidth");
  style = window.getComputedStyle(tableWidth);
  wdt = style.getPropertyValue('width');
  navWidth.style.width = wdt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  zoom: 175%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #AAC939;
  color: white;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flask Web Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="topnav" id="navWidth">
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Section 1</a>
    <a class="active" href="{{ url_for('show_table') }}">Section 2</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('admin') }}">Section 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container" id="tableWidth" style="min-width: 4000px;">
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped" style="max-width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {% for column_name in column_names %}
          <th>{{ column_name|replace('_', ' ') }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
          {% for item in row %}
          <td>{{ item|replace('_', ' ') }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```